# Having an issue with check_box and boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

I'm using a checkbox in the edit action, and when I go into the form and "check" the box, everything works fine. But then when I go back and try to "uncheck the box" it doesn't seem to save.

Here's my code for the form:

```
<%= f.label :winning, "Did this Proposal Win?", class: "input-title" %>
<%= f.check_box :winning, {}, true, false %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you providing this set of extra parameters? 
Do just this:

```
<%= f.check_box :winning %>
```

Eventually - try to use `1` and `0`, not `true` and `false`.